# how to get c++ compile results on linux with php

Tags: php, c++, linux, compilation, terminal

I want to get compile errors with php. I can take the outputs of some commands but I can't take compile command outputs. 
for example :

```
$compileCode = "g++ -o program program.cpp";
$output = `$compileCode`;
```

doesn't work. But

```
$output = `ls -l`;
```

works

Comment: you should read stderror stream, not stdout

Comment: Try `g++ -o program program.cpp 2>&1` to also read stderr.

Comment: No it should be `$x` how can I do it

Comment: You might want to use `popen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting stderr to stdout:

```
$compileCode = "g++ -o program program.cpp 2>&1";
$output = `$compileCode`;
```

If you want to see *only errors*, you can also redirect stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
$compileCode = "g++ -o program program.cpp 2>&1 1>/dev/null";
$output = `$compileCode`;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it worked :) I will accept answer in 9 minutes